# Rendering updated menu items on WooCommerce account pages in a new section

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm wanting to render some updated titles for each of the WooCommerce account pages. I have attached a design of what I'm hoping to achieve.

So far, I have updated the navigation links with the following.

```
/**
 * Rename and reorder My Account menu links
 */
$woocommerce_account_menu_items = array(
    'dashboard'         => __( 'Account overview', 'woocommerce' ),
    'orders'            => __( 'My orders', 'woocommerce' ),
    'downloads'         => __( 'My downloads', 'woocommerce' ),
    'payment-methods'   => __( 'Payment methods', 'woocommerce' ),
    'edit-account'      => __( 'My details', 'woocommerce' ),
    'edit-address'      => __( 'Address book', 'woocommerce' ),
    'customer-logout'   => __( 'Sign out', 'woocommerce' ),
);

function rb_reorder_woocommerce_account_menu_items( $menu_links ) {
    global $woocommerce_account_menu_items;
    return $woocommerce_account_menu_items;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'rb_reorder_woocommerce_account_menu_items' );
```

I have hooked in to `woocommerce_account_content` and rendered the section, however I'm not sure how to retreive these updated titles per page and render them. Any help or guidance is appreciated :)

```
/**
 * Add icon and page title before the account page content
 */
function rb_woocommerce_account_content() {
    global $woocommerce_account_menu_items;
    ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-card woocommerce-MyAccount-card--intro woocommerce-MyAccount-intro">
        <div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-intro__icon woocommerce-MyAccount-intro__icon--<?php // sanitize_title ?>"></div>
        <div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-intro__title"><?php // Get the updated title from $woocommerce_account_menu_items ?></div>
    </div>
<?php }

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_content', 'rb_woocommerce_account_content' );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Got it working with this.

```
/**
 * Change the entry titles of the endpoints that appear in the My Account page using the_title
 */
function rb_woocommerce_endpoint_title( $title, $id ) {
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'dashboard' ) && in_the_loop() ) {
        $title = 'Account overview';
    } else if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'orders' ) && in_the_loop() ) {
        $title = 'My orders';
    } else if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'downloads' ) && in_the_loop() ) {
        $title = 'My downloads';
    } else if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'payment-methods' ) && in_the_loop() ) {
        $title = 'Payment methods';
    } else if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-account' ) && in_the_loop() ) {
        $title = 'My details';
    }  else if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-address' ) && in_the_loop() ) {
        $title = 'Address book';
    }

    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'rb_woocommerce_endpoint_title', 10, 2 );
```